# Add an existing folder to ClickOnce installation

Tags: clickonce

I'm developing in VS2010 and I'd like to create a ClickOnce installation for my application. The startup project is called MyApp.
The solution also contains another project, let's call it DataProject, which has a folder in it with several xml files I need for the installation.
I can't add an existing folder (or at least, haven't found a way so far), and I don't want to add each file separately because if other files are added to the original directory, I'd like them published as well.
I suppose I'm looking for an option to add a complete folder as link or something similar. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on the project name in VS2010;
- Add... New Folder;
- Click on selected folder then Add... Existing item;
- Remember! You must change the BUILD ACTION (in file properties) to CONTENT.

Your folder should  include all files in  published solution via clickOnce.

Best regards

Comment: This won't work. I can add all the needed items manually, but what if the original folder updates and now has more files? Since my new folder is not a link to the original, it will not contain the new files.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Every time you publish a new version you can add the new files

Comment: This is high maintenance and error prone, which is exactly why I mentioned in my question that I do not wish to use such a solution.